# WifiP2pManager createGroup and removeGroup are failing with BUSY state

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

On both of my devices when I try to use `WifiP2pManager`'s  `createGroup` or `removeGroup` I get the `onFailure` callback with 2 (BUSY) as `reason`.

I've tried to use suggestion given here [WifiP2pManager return BUSY state on CreateGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252573/wifip2pmanager-return-busy-state-on-creategroup) (removing group before creating a new one), but it didn't help because I'm always getting `onFailure` 
callback in `removeGroup`.

Devices I tested on: LG Optimus G (CM 12.1 - Android 5.1), Gigabyte GSmart Guru G1 (stock Android 4.2).

**UPDATE**

The code is:

```
    manager.removeGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Debug.d();

            manager.createGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Debug.d();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    Debug.d("" + reason);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Debug.d("" + reason);
        }
    });
```

Comment: have you also checked that your Wifi is enabled from the settings ?

Comment: I don't understand why you are trying to createGroup during removeGroup? Can you explain that...
Do you intend to createGroup when some other group has been removed?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error because I tried to use `removeGroup` when group didn't exist. The solution is to check whether the current group exist before removing it or creating a new one.

Here's the working code (I use Retrolambda):

```
    manager.requestGroupInfo(channel, group -> {
        if (group != null) {
            Debug.d("group != null");
            manager.removeGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Debug.d();

                    manager.createGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Debug.d();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int reason) {
                            Debug.d("" + reason);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    Debug.d("" + reason);
                }
            });
        } else {
            manager.createGroup(channel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Debug.d();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    Debug.d("" + reason);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Dr.Jukka commented: Having the wifi turned off, can also cause a BUSY state. That was at least in my case.